# State not updating components (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have made a weather app using redux. Now, when the app loads the state is changed. But when I try to change the city name it doesn't changes.

How can I change the state from another component?

```
React.useEffect(() => {

        fetchLocation();

    }, [lat, long])
    
    
    
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
        await fetch("https://geolocation-db.com/json/")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                scity(result.city);
                console.log(ccity);
                dispatch(changeCity(ccity));
                fetchWeatherByCity(result.city);
            });
    }
    const fetchWeatherByCity = async (city) => {
        
        await fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather/?q=${city}&units=metric&APPID=${REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {

                setData(result);

                console.log(result);

                setState({});

            });
    };
dispatch(changeCity(ccity)); // changing the city 
// It is the current city, when the app loads
//First component
```

```
//changeCity action file
export const changeCity = (t) =>{
    return({
        type: "CHANGE_CITY",
        payload: t,
    });
}
```

```
//reducer file
const cn = (state = "", action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CHANGE_CITY":
            return state = action.payload;
       
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default cn;
```

```
// second component from where I want to change the city
<TextInput onChangeText={(value) => st(value)} style={styles.search_bar} placeholder="Another Location" placeholderTextColor="#fff"></TextInput>
<Button onPress = {()=> dispatch(changeCity(t))}></Button>


// this is second component
```

**Now, I want to update the city name from the second component.**

Comment: `dispatch(changeCity(ccity));` is it inside the `useEffect` of the first component? Does that useEffect has something inside the dependency array?

Comment: @Ammar No, it is not inside the ```useEffect``` of the first component

Answer (score 0):

You need return state instead of return assign value to state

```
case "CHANGE_CITY":
   return action.payload;
```

Comment: It does not work still it resets after .5 second